# intelligent image resizing in Yii

Tags: php, yii, image-resizing, yii-extensions

I want to create a thumbnail from an uploaded image, I want a yii extension or widget to do intelligent resizing, so the thumbnail should be exactly the same size that I specified to it?

Comment: itelligent resizing? do you mean? fit inside? fit width/height/ scaleFit?

Comment: @rorypicko fit inside